# ViewPagerFragment Tab doesn't Work

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

i create a viewPager and is work , my problem is for select a page i just can drag page but I want to click on the tabs to select the pages .

also i add (compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1')

[image]

my codes for FragmentPagerAdapter

```
public class Pager extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public Pager(FragmentManager fm) {

    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
            return First_Activity.newInstance();

        case 1:
            return Second_Activity.newInstance();

        case 2:
            return Third_Activity.newInstance();

        default:
            return First_Activity.newInstance();
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return 3;
}

//  --->>>Title Pages<<<---
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
            return " page 1 ";

        case 1:
            return " page 2 ";

        case 2:
            return " page 3 ";

        default:
            return "";
    }

}
}
```

my codes for MainActivity

```
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    Pager adapter = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}
}
```

Comment: Try tablayout.addOnTabSelectedListener, it will implement 3 override method onTabSlected, onTabUnselected, onTabReselected.

Comment: check your tabLayout id

Comment: share your layout

Comment: Did you try addOnTabSelectedListener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First declare this line in onCreate():**

```
   viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout)); 

Here , tabLayout is layout of your tabs you created in layout.
```

**Now add this function:**

```
   TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener tabListener = new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() 
  { 
      @Override
      public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)           
      { 
           viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition()); 
      } 
      @Override 
      public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) 
      { } 
      @Override 
      public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
      { } 
 };
```

This code will work for you surely.

Comment: i forget one Line Code...i use 
   
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
   
i cant use   
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

Comment: Why u can't use this lines??

Comment: addOnAdapterChangeListener
(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnAdapterChangeListener)
in ViewPager cannot be applied
to
(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener)